# Is there a site to obtain or create membranes?

Tags: one-topic-per-answer, databases, biomaterials, membranes

I am interested in creating an enterocyte intestinal basal membrane.

So, I wonder if there is a database or site where the membrane could be downloaded or created.

Answer (score 4):

## CHARMM-GUI

It is possible to create molecular systems with a membrane using [CHARMM-GUI](https://www.charmm-gui.org/). There is also a [tutorial](https://charmm-gui.org/?doc=tutorial&project=membrane) available. The current version requires a registered user account but it is free for academic use. If you need the system for molecular dynamics simulations, one can easily create input files, e.g. for [NAMD](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/namd/).